# Extraction of a part from an image

Tags: image, imagemagick, image-manipulation, perlmagick

I want to extract small rectangles from an image and then want to convert/roll the small rectanges into cylinders. No animation required. I just want to have the cylinders as images.

I am using [Perlmagick](http://p3rl.org/Image%3a%3aMagick) as API for [ImagemagicK](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Any help/suggestions shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the x,y coordinates and geometry of the rectangles you're trying to extract;

```
use Image::Magick;
...
my $image = Image::Magick->new();
my $x = $image->Read($filename);
    die "$x" if "$x";

# 100x100 is the size of the cropped image, the +40+40 are giving the x and y
# offsets (i.e. the upper-left coordinate of the cropped image)  
$image->Crop(geometry=>"100x100+40+40");
```

You'll have to be more specific about cylinders, but if it's what I think it is then check [Fred's Cylinderize script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderize/index.php). The examples given are ImageMagick command-line arguments so there's a bit of work to convert it to the perl equivalent (or you could call them using Perl's exec() function).